TypeScript iframe-resizer-react resize method not working
Seems like iframeResizerRef.current is defined but iframeResizerRef.current.iFrameResizer isn't?
I am using iframe-resizer-react to load an iframe.
import IframeResizer, { IFrameComponent } from "iframe-resizer-react";
...
const iframeResizerRef = useRef<IFrameComponent>(null);
...

<IframeResizer
  forwardRef={iframeResizerRef}
  src="https://myexample.com"
  style={{ minWidth: "100%" }}
  heightCalculationMethod="lowestElement"
  enablePublicMethods
  checkOrigin={false}
  frameBorder="0"
/>

I am posting an event to the parent to notify that there is a resize happening. Seems like iframeResizerRef.current is defined but iframeResizerRef.current.iFrameResizer isn't? heightCalculationMethod="lowestElement" doesn't seem to work when there's a dismissable error message, my iframe stays the same height after dismissing the error and not recalculating so i'm trying to resize it.
 if (data.message === "event.resize") {
   if (iframeResizerRef.current && iframeResizerRef.current.iFrameResizer) {
     iframeResizerRef.current.iFrameResizer.resize();
   }
  }

Any idea what am I missing here?
EDIT:
When I log iframeResizerRef.current it returns {moveToAnchor: f, resize: f, sendMessage, f} so tried to type current as below:
if (iframeResizerRef.current) {
  const iFrameResizer =
    iframeResizerRef.current as unknown as IframeResizer.IFrameObject;

  if (iFrameResizer) {
    iFrameResizer.resize();
  }
}

The resize doesn't seem to happen at all.

Yeah no one has ever made typing for the script in the iframe. Happy to add them to the project, but I’m not much of a TS coder.

This is now fixed in v5 of iframe-resizer.
